# Java exception class for failed thread start

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a thread that opens a socket at the beginning of its `run` method, after which it enters into a listening loop. I want the `run` method to throw a `RuntimeException` that tells me that the thread failed to start.

Is there such an exception **type** in Java? Something like `ThreadStartFailedException`?

Note: I don't want to open the socket in its constructor because I need this thread to be restartable, i.e. when I call `interrupt` on it, it gracefully closes its socket; if `run` is reinvoked on the same instance, the socket is recreated and the thread is running as if it were its first time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a [**RuntimeException class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). But throwing exception from `run` method and if you need to catch it later outside of the `run` method and it's corresponding class context, you will need to  use [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Runnable`.

> Is there such an exception type in Java? Something like
>   ThreadStartFailedException?

Nope, there is no such exception exists by default. Check the subclasses of `RuntimeException` from the documentation. You can subclass the `RuntimeException` if you want.

```
class ThreadStartFailedException extends RuntimeException
{

    public ThreadStartFailedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. I want a thread **type** that directly tells me that there was an error **initializing** the thread. A `RuntimeException` can occur any time during the lifecycle of the thread.

Comment: @Zoltán, sorry as i am having a little trouble to understand you. If you want to throw an exception and catch it outside the class context you can't actually use `Runnable` but you will have to use `Callable`

Comment: The note about the `Callable` is untrue. I can catch `RuntimeException`s from `run()` just as well. The only difference is that the `run()` method can't throw **checked** exceptions.

Comment: Yes, i have said that too: `if you need to catch it later` **outside** `of the run method and it's corresponding class context`. However, if you want to catch the exception in the `run()` method why not using state check with the means of field member(boolean type check) to responds that the thread actually failed.

Comment: I repeat: you **can** catch a `RuntimeException` outside the class and outside the `run()` method. E.g. `try { runnable.run(); } catch (RuntimeException e) { handle(); }` **will** work. Anyway, that's not what I was asking.

Comment: @Zoltán, thank you. Now i have got you that you are actually mentioning about `RuntimeException`. I think i should actually note directly to your edit when you meant an exception: `ThreadStartFailedException` :) Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42108/discussion-between-zoltan-and-sage)